# Cual es el motivo por el cual sale este error en python

Tags: python, tkinter

Solo quiero saber cuales son las causas del porque sale este error, he investigado y no encuentro nada al respecto, seria de mucha ayuda algun comentario al respecto

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!labelframe.!entry"
```

Comment: Cómo corres ese programa y qué más te aparece en el error (stacktrace)?

Comment: Sin ver el codigo que causa el error, imposible deducir la causa. Agrega un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable a la pregunta.